# What is Repeater.itemsLayout property for? How and in what cases to use it?

Tags: nativescript

This works as expected (without `<Repeater.itemsLayout>` and wrapped by `<StackLayout>`):

```
<GridLayout columns="auto, *" rows="auto">
    <Label text="Some Text" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="orange"/>
    <StackLayout row="0" col="1" backgroundColor="green">
        <Repeater items="{{ items }}">
            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ $value }}"/>
            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

And this as NOT expected (with `<Repeater.itemsLayout>` and without wrapping by `<StackLayout>`):

```
<GridLayout columns="auto, *" rows="auto">
    <Label text="Some Text" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="orange"/>
        <Repeater items="{{ items }}">
            <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                <StackLayout row="0" col="1" backgroundColor="green"/>
            </Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ $value }}"/>
            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: That looks like a bug with Repeater, you might want to report this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set `row` and `col` properties for `Repeater` tag. Like so:

```
<GridLayout columns="auto, *" rows="auto, *">
    <Label text="Some Text" row="0" col="0"/>
    <Repeater row="1" items="{{ items }}">
        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" />
        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ $value }}"/>
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer can be found here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6554#issuecomment-438167999

Answer (score 0):

Following code works because you are wrapping your Repeater in StackLayout and assiging it row and column and that is required as well if your putting that inside a GridLayout.

```
<GridLayout columns="auto, *" rows="auto">
    <Label text="Some Text" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="orange"/>
    <StackLayout row="0" col="1" backgroundColor="green">
        <Repeater items="{{ items }}">
            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ $value }}"/>
            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

If you do not want to wrap inside a StackLayout, you should assign row="0" col="1" to Repeater.
Now comes to your question, that use of Repeater.itemsLayout, it gets or set the items layout of the Repeater. Default value is **StackLayout with orientation="vertical"**.

So if you have a usecase where you want all the items in Repeater align horizontally, you should use following code.

```
<ScrollView row="0" col="0" orientation="horizontal">
    <Repeater items="{{ items }}">
        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" />
        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ $value }}" />
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand `...as that applies to all children of Repeater not to the parent`.
`Now comes to your question, that use of Repeater.itemsLayout, it gets or set the items layout of the Repeater.` means for me, that Repeater.itemsLayout is wrapper. That's what confusing me.

Comment: this thread might be useful https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/566